# Python import module not found errors

Tags: python

I have a directory setup as follows:

```
/directory
/directory/__init__.py
/directory/setup.py
/directory/app/db.py
/directory/app/__init__.py
```

The `/directory/__init__.py` file contains the line "import app" which then fails in `/directory/app/__init__.py` due to the line "import db" when I try to run the setup.py file.

HOWEVER, if I change the error line to "from app import db" then it works fine. Why is this? I'm guessing it has to do with the fact I run it from a parent directory. Is there any way to make this work? Or do I just change all of the imports to "from app import x" even when it's being called from the app folder?

Thanks for any clarification.

Edit: Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
import app
File "/directory/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
import db
ImportError: No module named 'db'
```

Edit2: Here's the `/directory/app/__init__.py` file (`/directory/__init__.py` is empty)

```
import db
from flask import Flask, render_template

DEBUG = True

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():

    return render_template()

def run(host, port):
    db.init_db()

    app.run(host=host, port=port)
```

Final Edit:
I had rephrased my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687023/why-dont-relative-imports-work-in-python-3#23687023) and was given the right answer. I wasn't sure if the python3 change was relevant. Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you post the error and stack trace

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this issue: https://gist.github.com/sharth/145bc486f10343a1869c

Comment: Can you share your `__init__.py` files and at least the first two lines of `setup.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @sharth, I tried to copy your file structure and replicate your error, but with no success. The only way I could get it to fail was to delete `db.py`. So you need to make sure that you actually do have a `db.py` file in your `app` directory.

Some ways that it could escape your attention:

1. You have a `db.py.txt`, or some other extension. It's possible your settings are such that file extensions are not automatically shown, so even though you think you are looking at a python file it is not actually a `.py` file.
2. The name got typo'd somehow. Maybe the filename, maybe the extension. For example, `db.oy`.
3. You have old `.pyc` files. While I was testing this I deleted `db.py`, but it still worked because I still had the `.pyc` files in the directory. It was only after I deleted them that the error occurred.

Comment: @user2744821 Try deleting all your `*.pyc` files and then test both `from app import db` and `import app`.

Comment: No good. Thanks for all your help though! It seems like the scope isn't adjusting and imports are always trying to go from the root folder... If I run the __init__.py from /directory/app/__init__.py then it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__.py` files in a directory should be empty, because that files are "magic files". 
So you must thinking about an redesign of importing your packages!
So, let your `__init__.py` files empty and then it should work!

Answer (score 0):

If pip doesn't work, uninstall python. Reinstall it with advanced options and enable pip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).